# Improve codes with multiple ifs and object key, value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Following codes look kind of spaghetti.. How can I improve this?

```
var obj = {
".*step1.*":"monday",
".*step2.*":"tuesday",
".*step3.*":"wednesday",
".*step4.*":"thursday",
".*step5.*":"friday",
};

sVal = window.location.pathname

if (flag == 1 && sVal.match(Object.keys(obj)[0]))
{ var str = Object.values(obj)[0];
} else if (flag == 1 && sVal.match(Object.keys(obj)[1]))
{ var str = Object.values(obj)[1];
} else if (flag == 1 && sVal.match(Object.keys(obj)[2]))
{ var str = Object.values(obj)[2];
} else if (flag == 1 && sVal.match(Object.keys(obj)[3]))
{ var str = Object.values(obj)[3];
} else if (flag == 1 && sVal.match(Object.keys(obj)[4]))
{ var str = Object.values(obj)[4];

console.log(str);
```

flag is defined already.
I wont mind using arrays instead of object if the codes can be cleaner.

Comment: Do you have some examples of pathnames?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var obj = {
  ".*step1.*": "monday",
  ".*step2.*": "tuesday",
  ".*step3.*": "wednesday",
  ".*step4.*": "thursday",
  ".*step5.*": "friday",
};

var flag = 1
var sVal = 'step3'

if (flag == 1) {
  var key = Object.keys(obj).find(k => sVal.match(k))
  var str = obj[key];
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making things much more difficult that you need to. Have an object with "normal" key names and then iterate over the keys with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) out if `sVal` [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) it.

```js
var obj = {
 step1: 'monday',
 step2: 'tuesday',
 step3: 'wednesday',
 step4: 'thursday',
 step5: 'friday',
};

const flag = 1;
const sVal = 'http://example.com?step=step3';

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

if (flag === 1) {
  const key = keys.find(key => sVal.includes(key));
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```